# Read input from one file and write it to another file in C

Tags: c, file, input, while-loop

I'm trying to read contents from a file "file.txt" and write each character from there to "copy.txt" but I get a weird character at the end of the "copy.txt" file.

I'm trying to open and close the two files and modify the body of the while loop in the program so that the character is no longer put to standard output (stdout).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char c;
  FILE *from, *to;

  from = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  if (from == NULL)
  {
    perror("file.txt doesn't exist.");
    exit(1);
  }

  to = fopen("copy.txt", "w");
  if (to == NULL)
    {
      perror("copy.txt doesn't exist.");
      exit(1);
    }
  do
    {
      c = getc(from);
      putc(c, to);
    }
  while(c != EOF);
  fclose(to);
  fclose(from);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You call `putc()` with the `EOF` result after `getc()` returns `EOF`.

Comment: Also, `c` should be an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: By the way @JamesR, the reason for using `int c` and not `char c` is that `EOF` is not necessarily representable in a `char`.

Comment: You can change the loop to `while ((c = getc(from)) != EOF) { putc(c, to); }`.

Comment: Please indent code consistently.   Suggest indent 4 spaces after each opening brace '{' and un-indent before each closing brace '}'.  Do not use tabs for indenting as each word processor/editor defined the tab stops/tab widths differently.  Use 4 spaces as that is visible even with variable width fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Problem lies in this loop:

```
do
{
  c = getc(from);
  putc(c, to);
}
while(c != EOF);
```

What you need to understand is the difference between a `do-while` and a `while` loop. A `while` loop will evaluate the expression BEFORE running the loop (thus the loop runs at least 0 times) and a `do-while` loop evaluates AFTER the loop circle (thus running at least one time).

So whats the problem? You read a character, write it to `copy.txt`, THEN evaluate if its `EOF` and exit the loop or not. Now, what happens when the last char is read from the file? The loop will run one more time, as the last character is NOT `EOF`. Your program will read one more character and write to the file. That is the character that you meant.

So in order to fix, you need to evaluate for `EOF` BEFORE writing. Here are two attempts, one that will keep your `do-while` loop and one that uses a `while` loop (more clear):

Do-While Attempt (not pretty and unneccessary if):

```
do
{
    c = getc(from);
    if (c != EOF) {            
        putc(c, to);
    }
}
while(c != EOF);
```

While Attempt:

```
while ((c = getc(from)) != EOF) {
    putc(c, to);
}
```

Comment: oops, these two lines are reversed from what they need to be:  `if (c != EOF) {
        c = getc(from);`

Comment: Why the downvote? Pls leave a comment if anything is wrong!